# Is this subset compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I was looking at an exercise on Compact Metric Spaces and I dont understand how to think about it.

We define in $\Bbb{C}^3 $ a function $ F : \Bbb{C}^3 \to \Bbb{R} $ , $ (x,y,z)  \to \vert{x-y}\vert + \vert{y-z}\vert + \vert {z}\vert$. Observe that this function is a norm.

If we take the set  S = {${ { (x,y,z) \in \Bbb{C}^3 : x = \bar{y} + \bar{z} }} $ } . Is S compact in ($\Bbb{C}^3 , F) $?

To be honest, I dont know how to begin. In fact, I dont even know how to calculate the distance between two points in $\Bbb{C}^3$. So I would appreciate some help on this exercise.  I have a strong intuition that the set S is not bounded, and therefore not compact (by Heine Borel), but I would need something more formal than an intuition.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $(x_n,y_n,z_n)=(2n,n,n)$ ?

Comment: The distance is induced by the norm: $d((x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)) = F(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2,z_1-z_2)$.

Comment: Is my intuition than S is not bounded correct?

Comment: That's what Surb witnessed, as $F(2n,n,n)=2n$..

Comment: You only need the easy side of H-B: compact implies bounded.

Comment: The non-trivial direction need not apply: closed + bounded need not imply compact..